# Почему объекты, добавленные в массив, все одинаковые, но консоль показывает на каждой итерации разные объекты

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты, map

Задание следующие, данные два массива, надо на основе массива map и массива users собрать новый массив объектов где в каждом объекте будут только те свойства которые перечислены в массиве map
Сделал следующее:

```js
const map = ["_id", "name", "isActive", "balance"];
const users = [
  {
    _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2853.33,
    age: 20,
    name: "Buckner Osborne",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EMPIRICA",
    email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com",
    phone: "+1 (850) 411-2997",
    registered: "2018-08-13T04:28:45 -03:00",
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 1464.63,
    age: 38,
    name: "Rosalie Smith",
    gender: "female",
    company: "KATAKANA",
    email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com",
    phone: "+1 (943) 463-2496",
    registered: "2016-12-09T05:15:34 -02:00",
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2823.39,
    age: 40,
    name: "Estrada Davenport",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EBIDCO",
    email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",
    phone: "+1 (890) 461-2088",
    registered: "2016-03-04T03:36:38 -02:00",
  },
];
let value = {};
let newArr = [];
let i = 0;
const result = (users) => {
  users.map((item, index, array) => {
    for (let key of map) {
      value[key] = item[key];
    }
    //console.log(value);
    newArr[i] = value;
    i++;
    //newArr.push(value);
  });
};
result(users);
console.log(newArr);
```

Вроде как можно все сделать проще через reduce, но как я начал можно решить?

Comment: ты добавляешь один и тот же объект, поэтому и получаешь один и тот же объект ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

1. основная ошибка - использование глобального объекта `value`. На данный момент три раза добавляется ссылка на один и тот же объект. Для решения достаточно перенести объявление внутрь `map`.

   ```js
   const map = ["_id", "name", "isActive", "balance"];
   const users = [{
       _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
       isActive: true,
       balance: 2853.33,
       age: 20,
       name: "Buckner Osborne",
       gender: "male",
       company: "EMPIRICA",
       email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com",
       phone: "+1 (850) 411-2997",
       registered: "2018-08-13T04:28:45 -03:00",
     },
     {
       _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
       isActive: true,
       balance: 1464.63,
       age: 38,
       name: "Rosalie Smith",
       gender: "female",
       company: "KATAKANA",
       email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com",
       phone: "+1 (943) 463-2496",
       registered: "2016-12-09T05:15:34 -02:00",
     },
     {
       _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
       isActive: false,
       balance: 2823.39,
       age: 40,
       name: "Estrada Davenport",
       gender: "male",
       company: "EBIDCO",
       email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",
       phone: "+1 (890) 461-2088",
       registered: "2016-03-04T03:36:38 -02:00",
     },
   ];
   let newArr = [];
   let i = 0;
   const result = (users) => {
     users.map((item, index, array) => {
       let value = {};
       for (let key of map) {
         value[key] = item[key];
       }
       //console.log(value);
       newArr[i] = value;
       i++;
       //newArr.push(value);
     });
   };
   result(users);
   console.log(newArr);
   ```

---

2. Неверно используется `map`: метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) уже создает и заполняет новый массив, нет нужды дублировать это вручную и терять при этом результат самого `.map`.

```js
const map = ["_id", "name", "isActive", "balance"];
const users = [{
    _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2853.33,
    age: 20,
    name: "Buckner Osborne",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EMPIRICA",
    email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com",
    phone: "+1 (850) 411-2997",
    registered: "2018-08-13T04:28:45 -03:00",
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 1464.63,
    age: 38,
    name: "Rosalie Smith",
    gender: "female",
    company: "KATAKANA",
    email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com",
    phone: "+1 (943) 463-2496",
    registered: "2016-12-09T05:15:34 -02:00",
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2823.39,
    age: 40,
    name: "Estrada Davenport",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EBIDCO",
    email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",
    phone: "+1 (890) 461-2088",
    registered: "2016-03-04T03:36:38 -02:00",
  },
];
const result = (users) => {
  return users.map((item, index, array) => {
    let value = {};
    for (let key of map) {
      value[key] = item[key];
    }
    return value;
  });
};
result(users);
console.log(result(users));
```